# How does the scipy.stats.moment function calculate the nth order moments (internally)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, statistics, curve-fitting

I'm trying to calculate the moments (about the mean) for a sample but I don't understand why the results from the scipy.stats.moment function **don't match** with the outcome of the computation when calculating the moments from *definition*. Here's my code:

```
#there are 15 data points 
x=[3.4,4.4,5.4,6.4,7.4,8.4,9.4,10.4,11.4,12.4,13.4,14.4,15.4,16.4,17.4]

#each point (say index i) in f corresponds to a point in x (indexed i)

f=[0.034,0.145,0.156,0.145,0.123,0.103,0.086,0.071,0.055,0.037,0.021,0.013,0.007,0.003,0.001]
#sum of f = 1
scipy.stats.moment(f, moment=[1,2,3,4],axis=0, nan_policy='propagate')

#RESULT array([ 0.00000000e+00, 2.94088889e-03, 5.61517926e-05, 1.42146527e-05])

#10.4 = mean of x
m1 = [(z-10.4)**(1) for z in x]
m2 = [(z-10.4)**(2) for z in x]
m3 = [(z-10.4)**(3) for z in x]
m4 = [(z-10.4)**(4) for z in x]

mom1= np.sum(m1*np.transpose(f))
mom2= np.sum(m2*np.transpose(f))
mom3= np.sum(m3*np.transpose(f))
mom4= np.sum(m4*np.transpose(f))

#RESULT -2.825, 15.643, -72.377, 432.211
```

There might be a mistake in the way in which I'm calculating the moments. Why am I **not** getting 1st moment = 0? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You seem to be expecting `scipy.stats.moment` to take `x` into account somehow, but that function doesn't receive `x` and has no idea that `x` even exists, let alone its relationship with `f`. It sounds like you want to compute something entirely different from what `scipy.stats.moment` computes.

Comment: If you want to see what `scipy.stats.moment` is actually supposed to compute, it's listed in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html).

Comment: @user2357112 So if I have two arrays: `x`, the independent variable and `f`, the dependent one (can be thought of as frequency of `x`, though all entries are less than 1), the `scipy.stats.moment` function cannot compute the moments?
Unless I somehow convert the whole thing into one array `X`

Comment: Ok, I found the mistake. Instead of '**10.4**' as mean of x alone, I should have taken `sum(x*f)/sum(f)` as mean, in my calculations. And also `scipy.stats.moment` would calculate moment only for a single list